# C++ 'wrapper class' for XML library

Tags: c++, wrapper

So I've been attempting to create some classes around the xerces XML library so I can 'hide' it from the rest of my project the underlying xml library stays independent from the rest of my project.

This was supposed to be a fairly easy task, however it seems entirely impossible to hide a library from the rest of a project by writing some classes around it.

Have I got the wrong approach or is my 'wrapper' idea completely silly?

I end up with something like this:

```
DOMElement* root();  //in my 'wrapper' class, however this DOMElement is part of the xerces library, at this point my 'wrapper' is broken.  Now I have to use the xerces library everywhere I want to use this function.
```

Where is my thinking gone wrong?

Comment: What are you doing with the XML? Reason I ask is this, instead of wrapping the XML library and exposing wrapper classes to your code, why don't you implement a simpler object model for what you are storing in the XML and expose that - then have a clean interface which can persist/extract that object model from the XML?

Comment: @Nim, the XML is used to communicate with a client over a network connection.  It persists the XML string to a certain 'format' of xml and I just need to take it apart when getting a request and put one together with answers.

Comment: so I'd say it's role in the whole project is not very big, however it still has to be there, as I cannot change the client side of things.

Comment: So basically it's used for messaging, is the format well structured with a well defined XSD?

Comment: @Nim, no I have to get the format from the existing program that sends requests and replies and base myself on the contents of that.

Comment: But it's a restricted format that has a well known structure? It must do to communicate with a client which you have no control over right? Even so, consider the separation approach, your program only ever deals with your own internal representation of the request/response and the encoder/decoder handles the conversion to/from wire format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend avoiding the wrapper in the first stage. Just make sure that the layers and their borders are clear, i.e. the network layer takes care of serializing/deserializing the XML, and from there on you only use your internal types. If you do this, and at a later stage you need to replace xerces with any other library, just replace the serialization layer. That is, instead of wrapping each XML object, just wrap the overall operation: `serialize`/`deserialize`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own abstract interface for a library is not a silly idea IF you have plan to change or to have the possibility to change the library you are using.

You should not rely on your library object to implement your wrapper interface. Implement your own structure and your own function interface. It will ease a lot of work when you will want to change how xml is implemented (eg: change library).

One example of implementation:

```
class XmlElement
{
    private:
    DOMElement element; // point to the element of your library

    public:
    // Here you define how its public interface.
    // There should be enough method/parameter to interact
    // with any xml interface you will use in the future
    XmlElement getSubElement(param)
    {
        // Create the Xmlelement
        // Set the DOMElement wanted
        // return it
    }
}
```

In your program you will see:

```
void function()
{
    XmlElement root();
    root.getSubElement("value"); // for example
}
```

Like that no DOMElement or their function appear in the project.

Comment: The downside with this approach is that you potentially end up wrapping lots of classes and re-implementing lots of methods which simply delegate to what you store - so with your XmlElement, now you have to re-implement the DOMElement accessor methods - seems a waste of time to me.. Esp. if down the line the xml wire format gets thrown away and you use a different messaging format!

Comment: I agree with you. BUT, reimplementing DOMElement accessor method is what a wrapper is supposed to do in order to hide its implementation. This is also why I specified on the begining of the topic that it should be use ONLY IF he plan to change the library behind it. How you implement it inside is up to you (my example may not be the best, It can use the system you describe...). But the wrapper interface must be clearly define.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments, I would take a slightly different approach. I would not want my codebase to be dependent on the particular messaging format (xml) that I am using (what if for example you decide to change the xml to something else later?) Instead I would work with a well defined object model and have a simple encoder/decoder to handle the conversion to XML string and vice versa. This encode/decoder would then be the bit that I would replace if the underlying wire format changed.

The decoder would take in the data read from the socket, and produce a suitable object (with nested objects to represent the request) and the decoder would take a similar object and generate the XML from it. If performance is not a primary concern, I would use a library such as TinyXML which is quite lightweight - heck, you can strip that down even further and make it more light weight...

Comment: +1: where I work we call the encoders and decoders "adapters", the role of the decoder is to take some data in input and build up a BOM, and if well written it completely insulates the rest of the code (we normally have a decoder interface). Regarding TinyXML: there is TiCpp which is a C++ wrapper over TinyXML and offers a nice C++ interface: http://ticpp.googlecode.com/svn/docs/ticpp.html